# Magento 2 : Information tab in Order View page design issue

Tags: magento2, php, design, magento-2.1.9

No error in console tab neither in network.
though i am getting design issue in order information.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Please run Following Commands in your console:-**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy


php bin/magento c:f
```

Also, check your Backend CSS Merged or not ?

Comment: i ran this command. though no change.

Comment: open in privet window

Comment: did all possible ways.

Comment: is your backend CSS merged?

Comment: No.. in Dom Order Content is coming inside <li> tag which is wrong. nothing to do with CSS